# How can I increase the thickness of bold textStyle font in android xml?

Tags: android, xml

/block of xml code

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tVUsername"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_start_margin"
        android:background="@null"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/dashboard_username"
        android:textColor="@color/blackColor"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.037"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.091" />
```

Image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdv20.png) is the output of the above block of code.

Image[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8o2z.png) , which I want.

Comment: use font family

Comment: @MajidAli used in above code,  android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"

Comment: use poppins bold if you have ttf file